# does influxdb is the right tool for website analytics?

Tags: influxdb

I want to store data of all page views on my site in InfluxDB and later I will need to get some analytics info about it. For example, "How many views does post X have?"

The problem is, as I understand it, if I have table `page_views` with tag(url) that is highly dynamic then I am going to have memory problems.

Right now I store this data in MySQL, but I am starting to face some problems as sometimes I need to store a 1000+ data requests per second.

So is InfluxDB the right tool for this kind of job? Is there some smarter way of storing each page view without tagging the url?

Comment: How many possible `url` values are there?

Comment: @MichaelDesa a lot and is only growing every day

Comment: Is a lot hundreds of thousands, millions, hundreds of millions?